# GAE System property rdbms.driver must be set

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, driver

Exception

> System property rdbms.driver must be set

I currently running my project through the console with:

appengine-java-sdk-*/bin/dev_appserver.sh

I have placed the Mysql driver in `appengine-java-sdk-*/lib/impl` as well as  `in war/WEB-INF/lib`, which this issue is usually solved by this action.

What I tried:

- restarted the server (Debian)
- using an older version of the SDK

but still without success, is is possible that this is due to a cache problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough that the driver is in your lib folder. This only means that it's there and ready to be referenced. The thing is, the devserver needs to know that. On the command line, when you invoke `devserver.sh`, try the flag `-Drdbms.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`, and let me know if that helps.